# How can I create overlapping trapezoids or successive rhombus from array?

Tags: javascript, css

I have been working on this for a while and would love some help.  I have two sets of divs of different lengths offset by varying distances which are being created from an array.

`Fiddle 1:`  [JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/muu94/1/)

Between these sets of divs I would like to dynamically create a connecting shape (trapezoid/rhombus like shape).  I was able to create the first one using CSS and borders.

`Fiddle 2:` [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/muu94/2/)

When I try to add successive divs I run into a problem.

`Fiddle 3:` [JSFiddle3](http://jsfiddle.net/muu94/3/)

The goal would look something like this (but created dynamically from the array rather than my Photoshopping here):

[image: Photoshop Image of Goal]

Any ideas?

I am not concerned about crossbrowser (I am only using FF), though such might be nice if it is easy.

Comment: Does the solution have to be html and css based, or would a canvas or svg based solution be acceptable?

Comment: I was really hoping to stick with CSS & JavaScript

Comment: I've tried working from your examples and then altering the points of correlation so that the slope is changed (reverse the two inner arrays for instance). I don't want to assume requirements for a solution that aren't needed. Will there ever be a need to display `correlationPoints = [[0,10,300,590,600],[0,290,300,310,600]]`? Is there a constraint other than preference for attempting to stick with CSS & JavaScript?

Comment: The `correlationPoints` will always start at `0` in both "subarrays" and be successively larger up to a maximum of `600`, with both ending the same.  Arrays could be of different lengths, however, such as both having 3, 4, 5 or more numbers, but always in unmatching pairs.  Thus:  `[[0,...,600],[0,...,600]]` will always be the same.

Comment: I took the liberty of demonstrating a hand made svg to show how you could do less work and also get `:hover` behavior. http://jsfiddle.net/hLZBL/1/ I think you might find the math easy as it becomes pretty direct drawing to the coordinates from the arrays.

Comment: That is pretty cool.  It tempts me to want to rewrite my entire page I have been building; apart from that, however, this solution doesn't help me.  The above question, though somewhat complex, is just a tiny piece of a huge page of correlated scientific dates that was all built with basic JavaScript and CSS.  The real page is using hundreds of pieces of data in numerous different ways.  Thanks for your fiddle, though, it is way cool.  You should put it as an answer, just stating that you know I wanted JavaScript, but that you could still answer it.

Comment: Would it be helpful to have the JavaScript that generates the svg, or do you just want an answer with the existing hand generated version? http://jsfiddle.net/hLZBL/2/

Comment: I think that would be good.  It makes it easier to test by fiddling with the points, adding points, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I know you wanted an HTML and CSS based solution, but here is a JavaScript solution for generating a svg based solution:

```js
var correlationPoints = [
    [0, 10, 50, 200, 600],
    [0, 200, 300, 400, 600]
  ],
  correlationHeight = 16,
  svg = document.getElementsByTagName('g')[0],
  patches = correlationPoints[0].length;

for (var i = 0; i < correlationPoints[0].length - 1; i++) {
  var newElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'path'),
    color = Math.round(((i + 1) / patches) * 255),
    path = [],
    c = 0;

  newElement.setAttribute('fill', 'RGB(' + color + ',' + color + ',' + color + ')');
  path[c++] = 'M'; // start move
  path[c++] = correlationPoints[0][i]; // start at top left corner x
  path[c++] = '0'; //top left y

  path[c++] = 'L'; //top right
  path[c++] = correlationPoints[0][i + 1];
  path[c++] = '0';

  path[c++] = 'L'; // top of angle right
  path[c++] = correlationPoints[0][i + 1];
  path[c++] = '20';

  path[c++] = 'L'; // bottom of angle right
  path[c++] = correlationPoints[1][i + 1];
  path[c++] = '40';

  path[c++] = 'L'; // bottom right
  path[c++] = correlationPoints[1][i + 1];
  path[c++] = '60';

  path[c++] = 'L'; // bottom left
  path[c++] = correlationPoints[1][i];
  path[c++] = '60';

  path[c++] = 'L'; // bottom of angle left
  path[c++] = correlationPoints[1][i];
  path[c++] = '40';

  path[c++] = 'L'; // top of angle left
  path[c++] = correlationPoints[0][i];
  path[c++] = '20';

  newElement.setAttribute("d", path.join(' '));
  svg.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

path:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Regular text.</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600px" height="60px">
    <desc></desc>
    <g class="correlations" alignment-baseline="baseline">
    </g>
</svg>
<p>Regular text.</p>
```

Comment: That is so awesome.  I am seriously going to have to consider redoing my whole page with SVG.  I hope this answer can help others also.  Amazing!

Comment: This is definitely the way I'd go: SVG.

Answer (score 2):

I found a page that shows some crazy amazing things you can do with CSS:  http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/.  I highly recommend it.  It turns out that you can create trapezoids in a much simpler method than I was originally employing.  Here is there very simple code for a trapezoid:

```
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

So, adjusting my approach a little, I was able to solve the problem with only CSS and JavaScript.  Here is what I came up with:

Fiddle 4:  [JSFiddle4](http://jsfiddle.net/muu94/4/)

The solution by Jason Aller is amazing, so please check that one out.